# How to set text to a text view from a string.xml and normal string at a time

Tags: android

R.string.Converasation contains Conversation
Here is the code

```
tv.setText(R.string.Converasation+"HELLo");
```

textview view is taking int value of R.string.Converasation and string value of HELLo and finally displays 2131034187Hello but i want ConverasationHello

how to resolve this..

Answer (score 31):

Try

```
tv.setText(getString(R.string.Converasation) + "HELLo");
```

Marc.

Comment: is my answer different from your?

Answer (score 20):

It should be like:

```
tv.setText(getString(R.string.Converasation)+" Hello ");
```

FYI, You can use either [getString(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29) or [getText(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getText%28int%29) to retrieve a string.

Answer (score 2):

@Mudassir everything works great. for me it's:

```
  display.setText(getText(R.string.counting_result) + " "+ counter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
  Resources res = context.getResources();
  float floatConverasation = 1.1f;
  String strfloatConverasation = "HELLO";
  tv.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"%s %f %s",
    res.getString(R.string.conversation), floatConverasation, strfloatConverasation));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

```
tv.setText(getText(R.string.Conversation)+" Hello");
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try same

```
 tv.setText(getString(R.string.Converasation)+" Hello ");
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by passing the string inside the resource
i.e.
getResources().getString(R.string.yourStringName)