# TextView setText is displaying ints instead of strings

Tags: android, textview, settext

I’m new to Android programming and trying to accomplish a seemingly easy task where I display a user’s Android Build version.  It took me a while to get past a runtime error where this line wouldn’t display an int, even though there were no compiler issues:

```
int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
mVersionTextView.setText(version);
```

I had to convert it to a string like this:

```
mVersionTextView.setText(String.valueOf(version));
```

Afterwards, I wanted to add some info to that number, to display some text right before the build, such as, “API level 21” for example.  I added a string constant called “api_level” and tried referencing it, but haven’t had any luck.

I’ve tried this:

```
mVersionTextView.setText(R.string.api_level + " " + String.valueOf(version));
```

And this:

```
mVersionTextView.setText(String.valueOf(R.string.api_level) + " " + String.valueOf(version));
```

… but those both display, “2131361827 21”.  In other words, it’s displaying 2131361827 instead of my “API level” text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getText` or `getString` like `getString(R.string.api_level)` for string resource.

Comment: Thanks.  I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938838/how-to-set-text-to-a-text-view-from-a-string-xml-and-normal-string-at-a-time) too afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

R.string.api_level is an Integer, use getString(R.string.api_level)
also Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is Integer